How to compare DateOnly to DateTime with FluentAssertions
Have a look at this simple test:
record Type1(DateOnly Date);
record Type2(DateTime Date);

[Fact]
public void Whateer()
{
   var type1s = new[] { new Type1(DateOnly.Parse("2024-06-01")), new Type1(DateOnly.Parse("2024-07-01")) };
   var type2s = new[] { new Type2(DateTime.Parse("2024-06-01")), new Type2(DateTime.Parse("2024-07-01")) };

   type1s.Should().BeEquivalentTo(type2s);
}

It's a simplified version of the issue I'm facing. The test above fails with:

Expected property type1s[0].Date to be <2024-06-01>, but found <2024-06-01>.
Expected property type1s[1].Date to be <2024-07-01>, but found <2024-07-01>.

How do I show FluentAssertions how to compare DateTime and DateOnly?

What would it mean if for example the DateOnly is 2024-06-01 but the DateTime is 2024-06-01 11:00:00 is that correct or incorrect? ie does the DateTime have to be at midnight in order to match?

I just care about the date

So why can't you just do type1s.Should().BeEquivalentTo(dateOnly.FromDate(type2s));

The example I provided is simplified, I have many more properties in Type1 and Type2,

I found the proper solution:
type1s.Should().BeEquivalentTo(type2s, options => options
     .Using<object>(ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(DateOnly.FromDateTime((DateTime)ctx.Expectation)))
     .When(info => info.Path.EndsWith("Date")));

